# Regex extract string after field

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I would like to extract a name string that always appears after a field.

The text looks like:

```
\r\n\r\nName    John Smith\r\n
```

The amount of spaces between "Name" and "John" can also vary between 3 and 8.

Any suggestions?

I tried using something like this, but it doesn't work.

`(?<=\nName)(.*)(?=\r\n)`

Comment: Provide executable code, otherwise people will not be clear about which characters are control characters present in the string, or simply "\" followed by "r", etc.

Comment: Thanks but not relevant in this case, I have no code, Just testing expressions on reg101.com.  "\r" and "\n" are escape sequences in ASCII and Unicode.

Comment: Your regex seems fine if it is supposed to work on text files created on Windows (since `\r\n` is used on Windows for newline but on Linux, it is just `\n`). Also, do you necessarily need to match a newline before the occurence of "Name"? This will only match a name field that begins on the newline preceeded by another line and will not match, say, a name field at the very beginning of the file in the first line or a name field in the middle of a particular line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
Name +([a-zA-Z ]+)
```

This works on Regex101

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use assertions, capture groups work better in this case.

`(?m)^Name[^\S\r\n]+(\S+(?:\s*\S)*)`

https://regex101.com/r/YkbNdA/1

where the name is in group 1

Answer (score 0):

É SÓ VOCE TESTAR

```
import re

text = "\r\n\r\nName    John Smith\r\n"
match = re.search(r'Name\s{3,8}(.*)\r\n', text)

if match:
    name = match.group(1)
    print(name)
```

`RETURN: John Smith`